# How to play announcement during call and can be heard on both sides caller and callee in Android Kotlin/Java?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I want to announce during a call that can be heard on both sides caller and attending person as well in Android Kotlin/Java.

```
// Playing from assets
val assetsFile = "record2.mp3"
val descriptor: AssetFileDescriptor = context.assets.openFd(assetsFile)

if (playFromAssets) {
    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(
        descriptor.fileDescriptor,
        descriptor.startOffset,
        descriptor.length
    )
} else {
    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(filePath)
}

descriptor.close()

mediaPlayer.prepare()
mediaPlayer.setVolume(1.0f, 1.0f)
mediaPlayer.start()
```

I tried this but when telephonemanager state is hookOff but issue is that it just hear on caller side not attender side.